# How copy the result of two labels?

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, calculator

I have code for the result copy button (from **displayResultLabel**)

How can I make that it was copied from the **two labels at once** (from **resultLabel, displayResultLabel**)

**resultLabel** - History

**displayResultLabel** - Result

---

**Example:**

> **resultLabel** - 5+22
>
> **displayResultLabel** - 27
>
> 5+22=27

**[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtevR.jpg)**

---

**I tried this, but I get this:** Optional ("5 + 22") = Optional ("27")

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "\(String(describing: self.resultLabelText.text)) = \(String(describing: self.displayResultLabel.text))"
```

**Button for copy**

```
...
let deleteActions = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Copy history",comment: ""), style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        UIPasteboard.general.string = self.resultLabelText.text
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
    })
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s because a labels text is optional, that´s why you get:

```
Optional ("5 + 22") = Optional ("27")
```

Do it like this instead:

```
if let resultText = resultLabelText.text, let displayText = displayResultLabel.text {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = "\(resultText) = \(displayText)"

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unwrap your values because `self.resultLabelText.text` and   `self.displayResultLabel.text` are optionals meaning that the value returned can be either nil or have a value.

If you are sure that you have a value and it can be convert just unwrap them by putting an exclamation mark like this : self.resultLabelText.text! and `self.displayResultLabel.text!` or use *Optional binding* as Rashwan proposed. It's the safiest way !

Apple doc for the basics : [Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: Try not to force unwrap values if possible.

Comment: That's why I mentionned Optional Binding ;)